# my unity broke, i dont have any custom or extra windows, the only assets i installed was the terrain tools

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

going on older or newer versions doesnt do anything, and the "Load default layout" and "revert to factory settings" doesnt do anything, it just brings me back to the failed to load window.

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDLGw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i fixed it by going in
C:\Users\YourName\Desktop\unity saves\ProjectName\Library and going in the
"CurrentLayout-default.dwlt" and opening it with notepad, then I removed everything in the file, and pasted this;

```
%YAML 1.1
%TAG !u! tag:unity3d.com,2011:
--- !u!114 &1
MonoBehaviour:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 52
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInstance: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabAsset: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_EditorHideFlags: 1
  m_Script: {fileID: 12004, guid: 0000000000000000e000000000000000, type: 0}
  m_Name: 
  m_EditorClassIdentifier: 
  m_PixelRect:
    serializedVersion: 2
    x: 2249
    y: 302.5
    width: 1206
    height: 715
  m_ShowMode: 4
  m_Title: 
  m_RootView: {fileID: 6}
  m_MinSize: {x: 875, y: 300}
  m_MaxSize: {x: 10000, y: 10000}
  m_Maximized: 0
--- !u!114 &2
MonoBehaviour:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 52
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInstance: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabAsset: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_EditorHideFlags: 1
  m_Script: {fileID: 12010, guid: 0000000000000000e000000000000000, type: 0}
  m_Name: 
  m_EditorClassIdentifier: 
  m_Children:
  - {fileID: 9}
  - {fileID: 3}
  m_Position:
    serializedVersion: 2
    x: 0
    y: 30
    width: 1206
    height: 665
  m_MinSize: {x: 679, y: 492}
  m_MaxSize: {x: 14002, y: 14042}
  vertical: 0
  controlID: 119
--- !u!114 &3
MonoBehaviour:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 52
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInstance: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabAsset: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_EditorHideFlags: 1
  m_Script: {fileID: 12006, guid: 0000000000000000e000000000000000, type: 0}
  m_Name: 
  m_EditorClassIdentifier: 
  m_Children: []
  m_Position:
    serializedVersion: 2
    x: 921
    y: 0
    width: 285
    height: 665
  m_MinSize: {x: 276, y: 71}
  m_MaxSize: {x: 4001, y: 4021}
  m_ActualView: {fileID: 13}
  m_Panes:
  - {fileID: 13}
  m_Selected: 0
  m_LastSelected: 0
--- !u!114 &4
MonoBehaviour:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 52
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInstance: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabAsset: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_EditorHideFlags: 1
  m_Script: {fileID: 12006, guid: 0000000000000000e000000000000000, type: 0}
  m_Name: 
  m_EditorClassIdentifier: 
  m_Children: []
  m_Position:
    serializedVersion: 2
    x: 0
    y: 0
    width: 228
    height: 394
  m_MinSize: {x: 201, y: 221}
  m_MaxSize: {x: 4001, y: 4021}
  m_ActualView: {fileID: 14}
  m_Panes:
  - {fileID: 14}
  m_Selected: 0
  m_LastSelected: 0
--- !u!114 &5
MonoBehaviour:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 52
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInstance: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabAsset: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_EditorHideFlags: 1
  m_Script: {fileID: 12006, guid: 0000000000000000e000000000000000, type: 0}
  m_Name: ProjectBrowser
  m_EditorClassIdentifier: 
  m_Children: []
  m_Position:
    serializedVersion: 2
    x: 0
    y: 394
    width: 921
    height: 271
  m_MinSize: {x: 231, y: 271}
  m_MaxSize: {x: 10001, y: 10021}
  m_ActualView: {fileID: 12}
  m_Panes:
  - {fileID: 12}
  - {fileID: 17}
  m_Selected: 0
  m_LastSelected: 1
--- !u!114 &6
MonoBehaviour:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 52
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInstance: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabAsset: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_EditorHideFlags: 1
  m_Script: {fileID: 12008, guid: 0000000000000000e000000000000000, type: 0}
  m_Name: 
  m_EditorClassIdentifier: 
  m_Children:
  - {fileID: 7}
  - {fileID: 2}
  - {fileID: 8}
  m_Position:
    serializedVersion: 2
    x: 0
    y: 0
    width: 1206
    height: 715
  m_MinSize: {x: 875, y: 300}
  m_MaxSize: {x: 10000, y: 10000}
--- !u!114 &7
MonoBehaviour:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 52
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInstance: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabAsset: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_EditorHideFlags: 1
  m_Script: {fileID: 12011, guid: 0000000000000000e000000000000000, type: 0}
  m_Name: 
  m_EditorClassIdentifier: 
  m_Children: []
  m_Position:
    serializedVersion: 2
    x: 0
    y: 0
    width: 1206
    height: 30
  m_MinSize: {x: 0, y: 0}
  m_MaxSize: {x: 0, y: 0}
  m_LoadedToolbars: []
  m_MainToolbar: {fileID: 18}
  m_LastLoadedLayoutName: Default
--- !u!114 &8
MonoBehaviour:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 52
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInstance: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabAsset: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_EditorHideFlags: 1
  m_Script: {fileID: 12042, guid: 0000000000000000e000000000000000, type: 0}
  m_Name: 
  m_EditorClassIdentifier: 
  m_Children: []
  m_Position:
    serializedVersion: 2
    x: 0
    y: 695
    width: 1206
    height: 20
  m_MinSize: {x: 0, y: 0}
  m_MaxSize: {x: 0, y: 0}
--- !u!114 &9
MonoBehaviour:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 52
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInstance: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabAsset: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_EditorHideFlags: 1
  m_Script: {fileID: 12010, guid: 0000000000000000e000000000000000, type: 0}
  m_Name: 
  m_EditorClassIdentifier: 
  m_Children:
  - {fileID: 10}
  - {fileID: 5}
  m_Position:
    serializedVersion: 2
    x: 0
    y: 0
    width: 921
    height: 665
  m_MinSize: {x: 403, y: 492}
  m_MaxSize: {x: 10001, y: 14042}
  vertical: 1
  controlID: 92
--- !u!114 &10
MonoBehaviour:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 52
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInstance: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabAsset: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_EditorHideFlags: 1
  m_Script: {fileID: 12010, guid: 0000000000000000e000000000000000, type: 0}
  m_Name: 
  m_EditorClassIdentifier: 
  m_Children:
  - {fileID: 4}
  - {fileID: 11}
  m_Position:
    serializedVersion: 2
    x: 0
    y: 0
    width: 921
    height: 394
  m_MinSize: {x: 403, y: 221}
  m_MaxSize: {x: 8003, y: 4021}
  vertical: 0
  controlID: 93
--- !u!114 &11
MonoBehaviour:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 52
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInstance: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabAsset: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_EditorHideFlags: 1
  m_Script: {fileID: 12006, guid: 0000000000000000e000000000000000, type: 0}
  m_Name: 
  m_EditorClassIdentifier: 
  m_Children: []
  m_Position:
    serializedVersion: 2
    x: 228
    y: 0
    width: 693
    height: 394
  m_MinSize: {x: 202, y: 221}
  m_MaxSize: {x: 4002, y: 4021}
  m_ActualView: {fileID: 15}
  m_Panes:
  - {fileID: 15}
  - {fileID: 16}
  m_Selected: 0
  m_LastSelected: 1
--- !u!114 &12
MonoBehaviour:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 52
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInstance: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabAsset: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_EditorHideFlags: 1
  m_Script: {fileID: 12014, guid: 0000000000000000e000000000000000, type: 0}
  m_Name: 
  m_EditorClassIdentifier: 
  m_MinSize: {x: 230, y: 250}
  m_MaxSize: {x: 10000, y: 10000}
  m_TitleContent:
    m_Text: Project
    m_Image: {fileID: -5467254957812901981, guid: 0000000000000000d000000000000000, type: 0}
    m_Tooltip: 
  m_Pos:
    serializedVersion: 2
    x: 2249
    y: 726.5
    width: 920
    height: 250
  m_ViewDataDictionary: {fileID: 0}
  m_SearchFilter:
    m_NameFilter: 
    m_ClassNames: []
    m_AssetLabels: []
    m_AssetBundleNames: []
    m_VersionControlStates: []
    m_SoftLockControlStates: []
    m_ReferencingInstanceIDs: 
    m_SceneHandles: 
    m_ShowAllHits: 0
    m_SkipHidden: 0
    m_SearchArea: 1
    m_Folders:
    - Assets
    m_Globs: []
  m_ViewMode: 1
  m_StartGridSize: 64
  m_LastFolders:
  - Assets
  m_LastFoldersGridSize: -1
  m_LastProjectPath: U:\layout
  m_LockTracker:
    m_IsLocked: 0
  m_FolderTreeState:
    scrollPos: {x: 0, y: 0}
    m_SelectedIDs: f4350000
    m_LastClickedID: 13812
    m_ExpandedIDs: 00000000f435000000ca9a3b
    m_RenameOverlay:
      m_UserAcceptedRename: 0
      m_Name: 
      m_OriginalName: 
      m_EditFieldRect:
        serializedVersion: 2
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 0
        height: 0
      m_UserData: 0
      m_IsWaitingForDelay: 0
      m_IsRenaming: 0
      m_OriginalEventType: 11
      m_IsRenamingFilename: 1
      m_ClientGUIView: {fileID: 0}
    m_SearchString: 
    m_CreateAssetUtility:
      m_EndAction: {fileID: 0}
      m_InstanceID: 0
      m_Path: 
      m_Icon: {fileID: 0}
      m_ResourceFile: 
  m_AssetTreeState:
    scrollPos: {x: 0, y: 0}
    m_SelectedIDs: 
    m_LastClickedID: 0
    m_ExpandedIDs: 00000000f4350000
    m_RenameOverlay:
      m_UserAcceptedRename: 0
      m_Name: 
      m_OriginalName: 
      m_EditFieldRect:
        serializedVersion: 2
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 0
        height: 0
      m_UserData: 0
      m_IsWaitingForDelay: 0
      m_IsRenaming: 0
      m_OriginalEventType: 11
      m_IsRenamingFilename: 1
      m_ClientGUIView: {fileID: 0}
    m_SearchString: 
    m_CreateAssetUtility:
      m_EndAction: {fileID: 0}
      m_InstanceID: 0
      m_Path: 
      m_Icon: {fileID: 0}
      m_ResourceFile: 
  m_ListAreaState:
    m_SelectedInstanceIDs: 
    m_LastClickedInstanceID: 0
    m_HadKeyboardFocusLastEvent: 0
    m_ExpandedInstanceIDs: c6230000
    m_RenameOverlay:
      m_UserAcceptedRename: 0
      m_Name: 
      m_OriginalName: 
      m_EditFieldRect:
        serializedVersion: 2
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 0
        height: 0
      m_UserData: 0
      m_IsWaitingForDelay: 0
      m_IsRenaming: 0
      m_OriginalEventType: 11
      m_IsRenamingFilename: 1
      m_ClientGUIView: {fileID: 0}
    m_CreateAssetUtility:
      m_EndAction: {fileID: 0}
      m_InstanceID: 0
      m_Path: 
      m_Icon: {fileID: 0}
      m_ResourceFile: 
    m_NewAssetIndexInList: -1
    m_ScrollPosition: {x: 0, y: 0}
    m_GridSize: 64
  m_SkipHiddenPackages: 0
  m_DirectoriesAreaWidth: 207
--- !u!114 &13
MonoBehaviour:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 52
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInstance: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabAsset: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_EditorHideFlags: 1
  m_Script: {fileID: 12019, guid: 0000000000000000e000000000000000, type: 0}
  m_Name: 
  m_EditorClassIdentifier: 
  m_MinSize: {x: 275, y: 50}
  m_MaxSize: {x: 4000, y: 4000}
  m_TitleContent:
    m_Text: Inspector
    m_Image: {fileID: -2667387946076563598, guid: 0000000000000000d000000000000000, type: 0}
    m_Tooltip: 
  m_Pos:
    serializedVersion: 2
    x: 3170
    y: 332.5
    width: 284
    height: 644
  m_ViewDataDictionary: {fileID: 0}
  m_ObjectsLockedBeforeSerialization: []
  m_InstanceIDsLockedBeforeSerialization: 
  m_PreviewResizer:
    m_CachedPref: 160
    m_ControlHash: -371814159
    m_PrefName: Preview_InspectorPreview
  m_LastInspectedObjectInstanceID: -1
  m_LastVerticalScrollValue: 0
  m_AssetGUID: 
  m_InstanceID: 0
  m_LockTracker:
    m_IsLocked: 0
  m_PreviewWindow: {fileID: 0}
--- !u!114 &14
MonoBehaviour:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 52
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInstance: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabAsset: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_EditorHideFlags: 1
  m_Script: {fileID: 12061, guid: 0000000000000000e000000000000000, type: 0}
  m_Name: 
  m_EditorClassIdentifier: 
  m_MinSize: {x: 200, y: 200}
  m_MaxSize: {x: 4000, y: 4000}
  m_TitleContent:
    m_Text: Hierarchy
    m_Image: {fileID: 7966133145522015247, guid: 0000000000000000d000000000000000, type: 0}
    m_Tooltip: 
  m_Pos:
    serializedVersion: 2
    x: 2249
    y: 332.5
    width: 227
    height: 373
  m_ViewDataDictionary: {fileID: 0}
  m_SceneHierarchy:
    m_TreeViewState:
      scrollPos: {x: 0, y: 0}
      m_SelectedIDs: 
      m_LastClickedID: 0
      m_ExpandedIDs: 42fbffff
      m_RenameOverlay:
        m_UserAcceptedRename: 0
        m_Name: 
        m_OriginalName: 
        m_EditFieldRect:
          serializedVersion: 2
          x: 0
          y: 0
          width: 0
          height: 0
        m_UserData: 0
        m_IsWaitingForDelay: 0
        m_IsRenaming: 0
        m_OriginalEventType: 11
        m_IsRenamingFilename: 0
        m_ClientGUIView: {fileID: 0}
      m_SearchString: 
    m_ExpandedScenes: []
    m_CurrenRootInstanceID: 0
    m_LockTracker:
      m_IsLocked: 0
    m_CurrentSortingName: TransformSorting
  m_WindowGUID: 4c969a2b90040154d917609493e03593
--- !u!114 &15
MonoBehaviour:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 52
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInstance: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabAsset: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_EditorHideFlags: 1
  m_Script: {fileID: 12013, guid: 0000000000000000e000000000000000, type: 0}
  m_Name: 
  m_EditorClassIdentifier: 
  m_MinSize: {x: 200, y: 200}
  m_MaxSize: {x: 4000, y: 4000}
  m_TitleContent:
    m_Text: Scene
    m_Image: {fileID: 2593428753322112591, guid: 0000000000000000d000000000000000, type: 0}
    m_Tooltip: 
  m_Pos:
    serializedVersion: 2
    x: 2477
    y: 332.5
    width: 691
    height: 373
  m_ViewDataDictionary: {fileID: 0}
  m_ShowContextualTools: 0
  m_WindowGUID: cc27987af1a868c49b0894db9c0f5429
  m_Gizmos: 1
  m_OverrideSceneCullingMask: 6917529027641081856
  m_SceneIsLit: 1
  m_SceneLighting: 1
  m_2DMode: 0
  m_isRotationLocked: 0
  m_PlayAudio: 0
  m_AudioPlay: 0
  m_Position:
    m_Target: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}
    speed: 2
    m_Value: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}
  m_RenderMode: 0
  m_CameraMode:
    drawMode: 0
    name: Shaded
    section: Shading Mode
  m_ValidateTrueMetals: 0
  m_DoValidateTrueMetals: 0
  m_ExposureSliderValue: 0
  m_SceneViewState:
    showFog: 1
    showMaterialUpdate: 0
    showSkybox: 1
    showFlares: 1
    showImageEffects: 1
    showParticleSystems: 1
    showVisualEffectGraphs: 1
  m_Grid:
    xGrid:
      m_Fade:
        m_Target: 0
        speed: 2
        m_Value: 0
      m_Color: {r: 0.5, g: 0.5, b: 0.5, a: 0.4}
      m_Pivot: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}
      m_Size: {x: 0, y: 0}
    yGrid:
      m_Fade:
        m_Target: 1
        speed: 2
        m_Value: 1
      m_Color: {r: 0.5, g: 0.5, b: 0.5, a: 0.4}
      m_Pivot: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}
      m_Size: {x: 1, y: 1}
    zGrid:
      m_Fade:
        m_Target: 0
        speed: 2
        m_Value: 0
      m_Color: {r: 0.5, g: 0.5, b: 0.5, a: 0.4}
      m_Pivot: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}
      m_Size: {x: 0, y: 0}
    m_ShowGrid: 1
    m_GridAxis: 1
    m_gridOpacity: 0.5
  m_Rotation:
    m_Target: {x: -0.08717229, y: 0.89959055, z: -0.21045254, w: -0.3726226}
    speed: 2
    m_Value: {x: -0.08717229, y: 0.89959055, z: -0.21045254, w: -0.3726226}
  m_Size:
    m_Target: 10
    speed: 2
    m_Value: 10
  m_Ortho:
    m_Target: 0
    speed: 2
    m_Value: 0
  m_CameraSettings:
    m_Speed: 1
    m_SpeedNormalized: 0.5
    m_SpeedMin: 0.001
    m_SpeedMax: 2
    m_EasingEnabled: 1
    m_EasingDuration: 0.4
    m_AccelerationEnabled: 1
    m_FieldOfView: 90
    m_NearClip: 0.03
    m_FarClip: 10000
    m_DynamicClip: 1
    m_OcclusionCulling: 0
  m_LastSceneViewRotation: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0}
  m_LastSceneViewOrtho: 0
  m_ReplacementShader: {fileID: 0}
  m_ReplacementString: 
  m_SceneVisActive: 1
  m_LastLockedObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_ViewIsLockedToObject: 0
--- !u!114 &16
MonoBehaviour:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 52
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInstance: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabAsset: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_EditorHideFlags: 1
  m_Script: {fileID: 12015, guid: 0000000000000000e000000000000000, type: 0}
  m_Name: 
  m_EditorClassIdentifier: 
  m_MinSize: {x: 200, y: 200}
  m_MaxSize: {x: 4000, y: 4000}
  m_TitleContent:
    m_Text: Game
    m_Image: {fileID: -6423792434712278376, guid: 0000000000000000d000000000000000, type: 0}
    m_Tooltip: 
  m_Pos:
    serializedVersion: 2
    x: 507
    y: 94
    width: 1532
    height: 790
  m_ViewDataDictionary: {fileID: 0}
  m_SerializedViewsNames: []
  m_SerializedViewsValues: []
  m_PlayModeViewName: GameView
  m_ShowGizmos: 0
  m_TargetDisplay: 0
  m_ClearColor: {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 0}
  m_TargetSize: {x: 640, y: 480}
  m_TextureFilterMode: 0
  m_TextureHideFlags: 61
  m_RenderIMGUI: 0
  m_MaximizeOnPlay: 0
  m_UseMipMap: 0
  m_VSyncEnabled: 0
  m_Gizmos: 0
  m_Stats: 0
  m_SelectedSizes: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  m_ZoomArea:
    m_HRangeLocked: 0
    m_VRangeLocked: 0
    hZoomLockedByDefault: 0
    vZoomLockedByDefault: 0
    m_HBaseRangeMin: -766
    m_HBaseRangeMax: 766
    m_VBaseRangeMin: -395
    m_VBaseRangeMax: 395
    m_HAllowExceedBaseRangeMin: 1
    m_HAllowExceedBaseRangeMax: 1
    m_VAllowExceedBaseRangeMin: 1
    m_VAllowExceedBaseRangeMax: 1
    m_ScaleWithWindow: 0
    m_HSlider: 0
    m_VSlider: 0
    m_IgnoreScrollWheelUntilClicked: 0
    m_EnableMouseInput: 1
    m_EnableSliderZoomHorizontal: 0
    m_EnableSliderZoomVertical: 0
    m_UniformScale: 1
    m_UpDirection: 1
    m_DrawArea:
      serializedVersion: 2
      x: 0
      y: 0
      width: 1532
      height: 790
    m_Scale: {x: 1, y: 1}
    m_Translation: {x: 766, y: 395}
    m_MarginLeft: 0
    m_MarginRight: 0
    m_MarginTop: 0
    m_MarginBottom: 0
    m_LastShownAreaInsideMargins:
      serializedVersion: 2
      x: -766
      y: -395
      width: 1532
      height: 790
    m_MinimalGUI: 1
  m_defaultScale: 1
  m_LastWindowPixelSize: {x: 1532, y: 790}
  m_ClearInEditMode: 1
  m_NoCameraWarning: 1
  m_LowResolutionForAspectRatios: 01000000000000000000
  m_XRRenderMode: 0
  m_RenderTexture: {fileID: 0}
--- !u!114 &17
MonoBehaviour:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 52
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInstance: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabAsset: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_EditorHideFlags: 1
  m_Script: {fileID: 12003, guid: 0000000000000000e000000000000000, type: 0}
  m_Name: 
  m_EditorClassIdentifier: 
  m_MinSize: {x: 100, y: 100}
  m_MaxSize: {x: 4000, y: 4000}
  m_TitleContent:
    m_Text: Console
    m_Image: {fileID: -4327648978806127646, guid: 0000000000000000d000000000000000, type: 0}
    m_Tooltip: 
  m_Pos:
    serializedVersion: 2
    x: 2249
    y: 726.5
    width: 920
    height: 250
  m_ViewDataDictionary: {fileID: 0}
--- !u!114 &18
MonoBehaviour:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 0
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInstance: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabAsset: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_EditorHideFlags: 0
  m_Script: {fileID: 13963, guid: 0000000000000000e000000000000000, type: 0}
  m_Name: 
  m_EditorClassIdentifier: 
  m_DontSaveToLayout: 0
```

(its the default layout this won't destroy your entire unity, lol)

Answer (score 0):

If you have this error only on one game project then try deleting these folders: Temp, Obj and Library, then open the project again.

If that doesn't work or this happens on multiple projects then you need to remove all, Unity and Unity Hub, ensuring that all the folders and registry settings are duly deleted, then reinstall all.

Before you uninstall all, remember to return your license in Unity Hub->Preferences->License Management.

Comment: it does only happen in one project, I've deleted the library and obj it still doesn't work. and I can't seem to find the temp file @PinoDeFrancesco